# MS.Graph api - how to get another user's events when 'Application Permission'

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

'Delegated permissions' works fine.

How to get another user's events when 'Application Permission' using Microsoft.Graph API.

I confirmed this error.

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: '**Code: ErrorAccessDenied
> Message: Access is denied.Check credentials and try again.**
> ClientRequestId: Below is the code that causes the error and the permission of the JWT value.

1. Code

```
private string ClientId = "{ClientId}";
private string TenantId = "{TenantId}";
private string SecretKey = "{SecretKey}";

private string[] scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

private async void Form1_Load(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Test2();
}

private async Task Test2()
{
    var confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                                .Create(ClientId)
                                .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token")
                                .WithClientSecret(SecretKey)
                                .Build();

    var authResult = await confidentialClient
                            .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                            .ExecuteAsync();

    GraphServiceClient graphClient =
                                                new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
                                                {
                                                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                                                                        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
                                                })
                                                );



    if ((await graphClient.Users.Request()
                                        .Filter("UserPrincipalName eq ' tester@tester.com'")
                                        .GetAsync()).FirstOrDefault()
                                        is User tester)
    {
        var calendar1 = await graphClient.Users[tester.Id].Events.Request().GetAsync();
        // Raise Error
    }
}
```

2. role ( JWT - Decode )

```
  "roles": [
    "User.ReadBasic.All",
    "OnlineMeetings.Read.All",
    "Calendars.Read",
    "Mail.ReadBasic.All",
    "Group.Read.All",
    "EventListener.Read.All",
    "Directory.Read.All",
    "RoleManagement.Read.All",
    "User.Read.All",
    "Domain.Read.All",
    "Schedule.Read.All",
    "Calendars.ReadBasic.All",
    "Team.ReadBasic.All",
    "Mail.Read",
    "AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All",
    "Mail.ReadBasic"
  ],
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1BVc.png)

my work history. to resolve

1. permission changed
   add/remove application permission & delegated permissions.
2. Authentication type change  ( secure key <-> certificate )
3. testing other code (using github sample project)
4. JWT Check & tesing Grape-explorer
5. Limiting application permissions to specific Exchange Online mailboxes( add / remove )
6. Configure application access to online meetings( add /remove )

I need your help

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try using [Client Credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider) to securely obtain tokens without user interaction.

I am able to see you have Calendars.Read application permission ,as you want access on behalf of user could you please try adding Calendars.Read delegated permission .

Hope this helps .

Thanks

Comment: thanks! your answer!
1. I used the client credential flow to get the token securely without user interaction.
2. Added delegation authority.
Still getting an error.

In another way, the token was issued to the account of the API owner. And it's being tested. ( PublicClientApplicationBuilder & AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword ) - This doesn't throw an error.

Comment: Modified and entered the entire code. This is the code using SecureKey.